# Mathematica custom notation / disable predefined function?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, notation

I cannot find how to use any variable name i want in mathematica.
(I've searched where i could but i cannot think of the correct terms to search for)

For example, I wanted to name one of my variables {pi}' (with {pi} I mean the greek pi, just cannot type it here).
However, there are problems. First, {pi} is already predefined as a constant equal to 3.14..
Second, the prime (') symbol is predefined as derivative.
So, {pi}' evaluates to 0& by default.

Another example would be, if i want to name my variable with a "0" in the exponent. However, I do not want mathematica to understand it as exponent, but just as name.

It would be fine if I could just deactivate that ' is interpreted as derivative, or that superscript is interpreted as exponent. But i would prefer some function which lets me define any collection of symbols as variable.

Can someone help?

Comment: The Notation Package (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html) may be of interest.  But I think that trying to (re-)define the interpretation of such basic symbols as pi and ' is a stony road leading to wailing and despair and that you would be better not starting down it.

Comment: Please read this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17617/121